# Google chart show title as label

Tags: javascript, php, sql, google-visualization, axis-labels

Working on a line chart in google chart. Having the issue that I cant show the title of the measurement as label. I am further going to get different measurements, right now I can only show one measurement at a time.

Here is the sql query and output in database:

[image]

This is the visualization, as you can see I want the routine.value to show the title: T_Badende_per_Time:

[image]

Code:

```
<?php

    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
    mysql_select_db("nih_bw", $con);

    $sth = mysql_query("Select measurements.title, routines.value, routines.date, routines.time from routines, measure_routine, measurements Where routines.id=measure_routine.routine_id AND measure_routine.measure_id=measurements.id AND measurements.title='T_Badende_per_Time' order by routines.date, routines.time;");

    $rows = array();
    //flag is not needed
    $flag = true;
    $table = array();

    $table['cols'] = array(

    array('label' => 'routines.date' & 'routines.time', 'type' => 'datetime'),
    array('label' => 'routines.value', 'type' => 'number'),

    );

    $rows = array();

    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $temp = array();
    // assumes dates are in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"
    $dateString = $r['date'];
    $dateArray = explode('-', $dateString);
    $year = $dateArray[0];
    $month = $dateArray[1] - 1; // subtract 1 to convert to javascript's 0-indexed months
    $day = $dateArray[2];

    // assumes time is in the format "hh:mm:ss"
    $timeString = $r['time'];
    $timeArray = explode(':', $timeString);
    $hours = $timeArray[0];
    $minutes = $timeArray[1];
    $seconds = $timeArray[2];

    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds)"); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['value']);


    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

    }

    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
     echo $jsonTable;   

?>


<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);



        var options = {
        /*width: 900, height: 900, */
          title: 'Visualization',
          curveType: 'function', 
           legend: { position: 'bottom' },
           pointSize: 5,
        vAxis: {title: "Values", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        hAxis: {title: "Time", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        explorer: { 
                actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'], 
                axis: 'vertical'}


        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);


      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want one line per measurement type, you need to pivot your data by `measurements.title`.  MySQL does not support the `PIVOT` statement, so you have to fake it like this:

```
SELECT
    routines.data,
    routines.time,
    SUM(IF(measurements.title = 'T_Badende_per_Time', , 0)) CAST(REPLACE(measurements.value, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) as T_Badende_per_Time,
    SUM(IF(measurements.title = 'measure_2', CAST(REPLACE(measurements.value, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0)) as measure_2,
    SUM(IF(measurements.title = 'measure_3', CAST(REPLACE(measurements.value, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0)) as measure_3
    etc...
FROM
    routines
    INNER JOIN measure_routine ON routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id
    INNER JOIN measurements ON measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id
WHERE
    <conditions>
GROUP BY routines.date, routines.time
ORDER BY routines.date, routines.time
```

Then in PHP, create one column for each measurement type:

```
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'routines.date' & 'routines.time', 'type' => 'datetime'),
    array('label' => 'T_Badende_per_Time', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'measure_2', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'measure_3', 'type' => 'number')
    // etc
);

$rows = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $temp = array();
    // assumes dates are in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"
    $dateString = $r['date'];
    $dateArray = explode('-', $dateString);
    $year = $dateArray[0];
    $month = $dateArray[1] - 1; // subtract 1 to convert to javascript's 0-indexed months
    $day = $dateArray[2];

    // assumes time is in the format "hh:mm:ss"
    $timeString = $r['time'];
    $timeArray = explode(':', $timeString);
    $hours = $timeArray[0];
    $minutes = $timeArray[1];
    $seconds = $timeArray[2];

    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds)");
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['T_Badende_per_Time']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['measure_2']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['measure_3']);
    // etc..

    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the sql query worked great. But having on issue as seen here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1znyjx5zs0qtr2d/saved.png  the SQL squery removes the decimal values and make it integer. Another question is if google chart supports decimal or do I have to string replace it to dot, if so how would that be done. Thanks for helping, really appriciete it.

Comment: That is odd behavior.  I wonder if the `SUM` is type-converting your data fields to integers because of the `0`.  Try casting the 0's as the same data type as your data columns, eg: `CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(18, 2))`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, and it worked perfect. Could you please show me how to implement it in the sql query you have showed me ? https://www.dropbox.com/s/bg5jq7hmz6wehm2/replace.png I am really thankfull for all of your time and energy.

Comment: You need to cast `measurements.value` in each `SUM`.  I'll edit the answer with examples.

Comment: Thanks! I am having another issue. If you please could take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806386/google-chart-values-from-different-times

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to set the `vAxis.title`. You already set it in your line 73 (`vAxis: {title: "Values"}`) but it needs to be set to a variable from PHP:

```
[...]
$vAxis = false;
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    // this will overwrite itself, it looks to me that in your case it doesn't matter
    $vAxis = $r["title"];
    [...]
```

and then output it

```
vAxis: {title: "<?=$vAxis ?: "default title"; ?>"}
```