# Google chart values from different times

Tags: mysql, sql, google-visualization, visualization

Working on a google line chart. Having the problem that two of the values (T_Temperatur) And (T_Badende_per_Time) is inserted into the database at the same time with one submit. But not T_Lufttemperatur. That is creating problem with the chart, which is also showing the nulls. So this is my sql:

[image]

This is the google chart:

[image]

Code:

```
<?php

    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
    mysql_select_db("nih_bw", $con);

    $sth = mysql_query("
SELECT routines.date, routines.time, 
SUM( IF( measurements.title =  'T_Temperatur', CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ), 0 ) ) AS Temperatur, 

SUM( IF( measurements.title =  'T_Badende_per_Time', CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ), 0 ) ) AS Badende,

SUM( IF( measurements.title =  'T_Luft_Temperatur', CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ), 0 ) ) AS Luft

FROM routines
INNER JOIN measure_routine ON routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id
INNER JOIN measurements ON measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id
GROUP BY routines.date, routines.time
ORDER BY routines.date, routines.time;  


    ;");


    $rows = array();
    //flag is not needed
    $flag = true;
    $table = array();

    $table['cols'] = array(

    array('label' => 'routines.date' & 'routines.time', 'type' => 'datetime'),
   array('label' => 'Temperatur', 'type' => 'number'),  
   array('label' => 'Badende', 'type' => 'number'),
   array('label' => 'Luft', 'type' => 'number'),    

    );

    $rows = array();

    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $temp = array();
    // assumes dates are in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"
    $dateString = $r['date'];
    $dateArray = explode('-', $dateString);
    $year = $dateArray[0];
    $month = $dateArray[1] - 1; // subtract 1 to convert to javascript's 0-indexed months
    $day = $dateArray[2];

    // assumes time is in the format "hh:mm:ss"
    $timeString = $r['time'];
    $timeArray = explode(':', $timeString);
    $hours = $timeArray[0];
    $minutes = $timeArray[1];
    $seconds = $timeArray[2];

    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds)"); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Temperatur']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Badende']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Luft']);


    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

    }

    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    // echo $jsonTable;     

?>


<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);



        var options = {
        /*width: 900, height: 900, */


          title: 'Visualization',
          curveType: 'function', 
           legend: { position: 'bottom' },
           pointSize: 5,
        vAxis: {title: "Values", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        hAxis: {title: "Time", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        explorer: { 
                actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'], 
                axis: 'vertical'}




        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);


      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

jsontable:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"routines.dade","type":"datetime"},{"label":"Temperatur","type":"number"},
{"label":"Badende","type":"number"},{"label":"Luft","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":
[{"v":"Date(2014, 3, 02, 09, 04, 12)"},{"v":"29.23"},{"v":"55.00"},{"v":""}]},{"c":
[{"v":"Date(2014, 3, 02, 10, 04, 01)"},{"v":"23.34"},{"v":"34.00"},{"v":""}]},{"c":
[{"v":"Date(2014, 3, 02, 10, 04, 39)"},{"v":"43.54"},{"v":"39.00"},{"v":""}]},{"c":
[{"v":"Date(2014, 3, 02, 10, 04, 53)"},{"v":""},{"v":""},{"v":"23.23"}]}]}
```

Please feel free to ask if you need more info provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the 0's in the query with nulls:

```
SELECT routines.date, routines.time, 
    SUM( IF( measurements.title = 'T_Temperatur', CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ), null ) ) AS Temperatur, 
    SUM( IF( measurements.title = 'T_Badende_per_Time', CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ), null ) ) AS Badende,
    SUM( IF( measurements.title = 'T_Luft_Temperatur', CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ), null ) ) AS Luft
FROM routines
INNER JOIN measure_routine ON routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id
INNER JOIN measurements ON measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id
GROUP BY routines.date, routines.time
ORDER BY routines.date, routines.time;
```

**[EDIT - added PHP code to avoid casting the numbers as strings]**

When inputting your data, don't cast them as strings:

```
$temp[] = array('v' => $r['Temperatur']);
$temp[] = array('v' => $r['Badende']);
$temp[] = array('v' => $r['Luft']);
```

and use the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option in the `json_encode` call:

```
$jsonTable = json_encode($table, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't change the chart: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rsmhanxhto5is4c/problem.png When I mouseover the dot, now it doesn't show anything before it showed 0.

Comment: Update your question with the output of the line `var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);`

Comment: If I understood you correct, you wanted the output of the jsonTable, i have edited it in.

Comment: Ahh, I think I see the problem.  You don't want to translate your database outputs to strings, you want them to stay as numbers.  I'll update my answer with adjusted PHP code.

Comment: Hmm! I see, hopefully that will fix the problem! Once again, I really appreciate you taking your time and energy to help.

Comment: That is freaking awesome! Worked brilliant. I have a off topic question, is it possible to make the line chart go more in the x axis? So you can see a longer time perspective ?

Comment: Set the `hAxis.viewWindow.min` and/or `hAxis.viewWindow.max` options to set the range of values displayed on the axis.